# AWS cli not behaving as expected , w.r.t UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have one S3 bucket with no resource policy. I create policy explicitly that restrict IAM user access to this bucket by creating below policy and attaching it to IAM user.

If I login using that user in console , I see that list of bucket and can do action that are defined in policy. but when I try doing `aws s3 ls`  is give me below error

`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied`

Policy

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": "AllowAppsS3ListAccess"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ],
            "Sid": "AllowAppsS3Access"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Comment: FYI the 2nd statement includes the resource `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name` which is not a valid resource for any of the associated (all object-level) actions. You should remove it.

Comment: I would temporarily add another IAM user (with programmatic access), give that user an IAM policy simply allowing `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` on resource `*`, add a `temp` awscli profile for that user, and re-test with `aws s3 ls --profile temp`.

Comment: Thanks Jarmod, I tried this as well. No luck I get the same access denied error. from console I can see the buckets but from cli I can not

Comment: Ensure your awscli is up to date and verify the presented credentials are correct using `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile temp`.